# solr org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Im trying the SolrServer.ping(); to see if solr is up and running. and get the above exception even when the server is running.

```
    public boolean isServerAvailable(String serverAddress, Integer serverPort) {
    boolean isAlive = true;


    try {
    HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://" + serverAddress + ":" + serverPort + "/solr/#//");
        solrServer.setParser(new XMLResponseParser() );
        SolrPingResponse response = solrServer.ping();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        isAlive = false;
    }

    return isAlive;
}
```

I tried changing the parser to XML too. on my solrconfig.xml I have

```
         <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
```

I can't change that to anything else.

Comment: What version of Solr are you running? Are you using Jetty or something else? Can you access Solr normally via http?

Comment: The app container log will most certainly have some sort of error message, as the error is usually caused by the container serving an error message instead of the expected content from Solr.